# The code showing me random types of number is different ide. Can function loop is possible

Tags: python, function, loops

```py
def one(num):
    count=0
    count=num
    print(count)
    try:
        two(count)
    except RecursionError:
        two(count)
def two(num):
    number=num
    number+=1
    try:
        one(number)
    except RecursionError:
        one(number)
one(0)
```

It is showing me random types of number is different ide.
Can function loop is possible (but the error comes after 400 or 500 or 0).

Comment: Can you add more explanation. Your problem is not clear,.

Answer (score 0):

In your various environments (IDEs), try:

```py
import sys
print(sys.getrecursionlimit())
```

That limit may be different depending on your setup.